# Vb.net checking if a number is a mutliple of another number

Tags: vb.net, variables

I need to check if a number is a multiple of another number. So I can output a certain string or do a certain function. Is there a simple way or easy way of doing this.

Comment: Use the [`Mod` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx): `If 10 Mod 5 = 0 Then ...`

Comment: exactly, it returns the remainder which is 0 if it's a multiple. `11 Mod 5` returns 1 because 11 is not divisible through 5, 1 remains

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for the help

Comment: @bob I am not one who voted this down, but I suspect they did because it is something that could have been easily looked up, and because it is a very basic concept, with analogous operators in pretty much all programming languages. The implication is "do a bit more research before asking here."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "modulus" or "mod" operator gives you the remainder of a division operation. So if the remainder is 0, then you know the numbers are multiples. This is also used for determining if numbers are odd or even. Simply do a mod (%) with 2, and if the answer is 0 then it's even, and 1 it's odd